# How to write a method/new constructor for an existing class/structure? Padding(int Horizontal, int Vertical)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to learn C# by building a Windows Form and I've run across something that I haven't been able to find the answer to searching. My search results may have already provided me the answer (that it's not possible), but I wanted to confirm before giving up.

I'm creating a form that has multiple Panels and/or FlowLayoutPanels, each with multiple controls. **I'm attempting to dynamically calculate the amount of space that the controls take up so I can add Padding to the Panel/FlowLayoutPanel to somewhat center the controls**. There may be better ways of doing this using Anchors, but I'm learning and this was the best way I could think of to tackle this specific problem to help me learn.

As I've worked through the problem, **I've realized that the Padding structure doesn't have a constructor that would make things much easier on me that I've seen in other apps (specifically Microsoft Office & VBA)**. I want to be able to create a `new Padding()` that has a constructor that accepts `(int Horizontal, int Vertical)` or just `(int Horizontal)` or just `(int Vertical)` where the 'Horizontal' int is copied to the .Left and .Right properties of a control, and the 'Vertical' int is copied to the .Top and .Bottom properties of a control.

So, my question: **Is there a way to write a constructor for an existing class/structure or some way to overload the Padding structure that will allow me to obtain the padding I want with only two values instead of all four?**

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive a new class from an existing class, provided the existing class is not `sealed`. But in your case the class is actually a `struct`, and you cannot derive from a struct.

Through *extension methods* you can add instance-like methods to existing classes, but you can't add static methods or constructors to existing classes.

When I'm in such a situation, I just create a new static utility class that does what I want. For example:

```
public static class PaddingUtil
{
    public static Padding FromHV(int horizontal, int vertical)
    {
        return new Padding(horizontal, vertical, horizontal, vertical);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Padding p = PaddingUtil.FromHV(10, 20);
```

---

Your questions indicate you don't understand the basics of C#. I suggest you get a book about C# and read it.

But to help you out for now:

- To assign a value to a field or property of an object, just do this:

  ```
  Padding p = PaddingUtil.FromHV(10, 20);
  myControl.Padding = p;
  ```

  Or equivalently:

  ```
  myControl.Padding = PaddingUtil.FromHV(10, 20);
  ```
- To get the current value of a field or property of an object, just do this:

  ```
  Padding p = myControl.Padding;
  ```
- To change some properties on a `Padding` struct:

  ```
  Padding oldPadding = myControl.Padding;
  Padding newPadding = new Padding(
      10, // Left
      oldPadding.Top,
      10, // Right
      oldPadding.Bottom);
  myControl.Padding = newPadding;
  ```

You can turn the last example into an *extension method*. Google it, or search Stack Overflow.

Comment: How would I use it for an existing control? `myControl.Padding = new PaddingUtil.FromHV(10, 20);`?

Comment: Also, I added an edit above that shows two more example constructors that I failed to mention and mistakenly assumed would be implied by my only example constructor (sorry). How would I use your example to set just `(int Horizontal)` without affecting the existing .Top/.Bottom values for the control? I'd probably have to pass a Control parameter with the integer value or something similar in the method, right?

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me...like I said, I'm learning. I didn't consider the possibility that I could create variables of type Padding. It didn't click from your first example that that was what you were doing. Sorry for that and thanks again.

Comment: @user2063351 No need to apologize. Just try and learn, search and learn, and then ask and learn. Good luck learning!